# Get reference to a JQuery UI Accordion Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a JQuery Accordion as below;

```
<div id="accordion">
 <h3 class="ui-accordion-header"><a id="link1" href="#">First Header</a></h3>
  <div id="div1">First Content</div>
 <h3 class="ui-accordion-header"><a id="link2" href="#">Second Header</a></h3>
  <div id="div2">Second Content</div>
</div>
```

The Accordion is generated by this:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
  collapsible:true,
  active:false,
  navigation:true,
  autoHeight:false,
  change:function(event, ui){
    var index = $(this).find("h3").index(ui.newHeader[0]);
    var header = $(this).find("h3")[index].find("a"); //<--- problem line
    var currentHeaderID = (header.attr("id")); //<--id that I need
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct3rA/1/)

The accordion is loading up fine. I'm trying to achieve two things.

**1-** Get the ID of the href element inside the  tag of the header that was just opened (i.e. ids link1 and link2).  The code above inside the change event is giving me the index of the header.  But I'm struggling to get the next line (`var header = ....`) working.  would you be able to

**2- RESOLVED** When a user clicks on an already opened header, that section is closed, so effectively all sections become closed.  I'm not sure how I can achieve this.  Are you able to help?

Thanks

Comment: #2 is the default behavior when you use `collapisble: true`

Comment: When `header1` is open and you click `header2`, then `header1` is closed and `header2` is opened.  However what I would like is when `header1` is opened and you clicked on `header1` again, then `header1` to be closed. That does not happen at the moment.

Comment: yes if you have collapisble set it should work that way: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible Its not working now because youve mispelled the option its `collapsible` NOT `collapsable`

Comment: Sivakanesh, do you know that ID's are case sensitive and that they cannot start with a 'number' ? use rather something like id="link1" id="link2" ...etc.

Comment: Updated the questions and put up a JSFiddle link. Tx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the accordion changes, a jQuery object wrapping the active header's `<h3>` element is passed in `ui.newHeader`, so you only have to use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var currentHeaderID = ui.newHeader.find("a").attr("id");
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct3rA/2/).